# Sqoop export having duplicate entries in to table without primary key

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I have a table department_id,department_name,LastModifieddate;

when i run the command like below

```
sqoop export  \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://ip-172-31-13-154:3306/sqoopex" \
 --username sqoopuser \
 --password NHkkP876rp \
 --table dep_prasad \
 --input-fields-terminated-by '|' \
 --input-lines-terminated-by '\n' \
 --export-dir /user/venkateswarlujvs2821/dep_prasad/ \
 --num-mappers 2 \
 --outdir /user/venkateswarlujvs2821/dep_prasad
```

It works fine and is inserting records

when i modify the file which is there in HDFS and adding some more records
and when i try to export it .It is inserting duplicate entries in to my sql
i am using the following sqoop command for the second time.

```
sqoop export  \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://ip-172-31-13-154:3306/sqoopex" \
 --username sqoopuser \
 --password NHkkP876rp \
 --table dep_prasad \
 --input-fields-terminated-by '|' \
 --input-lines-terminated-by '\n' \
 --update-key department_id \
 --update-mode allowinsert \
 --export-dir /user/venkateswarlujvs2821/dep_prasad/ \
 --num-mappers 2 \
 --outdir /user/venkateswarlujvs2821/dep_prasad
```

Note:My table DO NOT HAVE PRIMARY KEY

I want to update only the new records how can i do that?

Comment: Anybody can help me please ?

Comment: just make **department_id**   as primary it will be work fine. hope it helps.:)

Comment: yes i know it will work .But is there any solution without make that as a primary key

Comment: Simple solution is to make department_id column in your MySQL table as Primary/Unique key